# Spring mvc 4.1 inject beans based on if else condition

Tags: java, spring-mvc

i have requirement that

```
    if(condition.equals("first")){
          //here want to inject First bean object at run time 
} else if(condition.equals("second"){
          //here want to inject Second bean object 
}
```

like wise based on condition want to inject that particular bean at runtime
   is it possible in spring MVC 4.1 ? 
    if possible please help me that

```
thanks for u response
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537620/conditional-injection-of-bean

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31474570/java-ee-interface-conditional-inject

Comment: Thanks a lot for u r respone..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for u r respone..
Can i use @Autowired in place of @Response as am injecting spring bean in ReportFactory

Ex: 
@Autowired
private ExcelReport excelReport;